# Installing Oracle JDK using Ansible

Tags: java, ansible, oracle

I've been researching this for a while and it seems that installing an Oracle JDK rather than OpenJDK through Ansible is much more troublesome due to licensing from Oracle.
I've found some community solutions on [Ansible Galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/search?deprecated=false&keywords=&order_by=-relevance), namely these two:

- [azavea.ansible-java](https://github.com/azavea/ansible-java) which isn't working due to a deprecated PPA repository the Ansible roles are using
- [ansiblebit.oracle-java](https://galaxy.ansible.com/ansiblebit/oracle-java) which seems promising, however this does require an `oracle_java_apt_repository` to be set, which we currently do not have.

It needs to be Oracle JDK specifically unfortunately, so there is no work around to changing to OpenJDK.
Is there any other way to install Oracle Java using Ansible, or at least be able to acquire a PPA to install the JDK from?

Thanks.